# How the Write/Read Capacity Units be calculated actually?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

According to the doc

> One read request unit represents one strongly consistent read request, or two eventually consistent read requests, for an item up to 4 KB in size.

So how the "4KB" is going to be calculated?

For example

- In case of [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html), even if update a single attribute of an item, will it be counted as the whole item's size?
- In case of [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html), even if only select a single attribute of the item via [ProjectionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ProjectionExpression), will it be counted as the whole item's size? or just the projected item's size?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that both those cases reduce network usage, but not what DDB actually has to read from / write to storage.

So the size is strictly how big the DDB entry is as a whole.

Just like when you "filter" a Query() or Scan() operation, the entries thrown away still consume RCU.  Note that unlike a GetItem, if your entries are 1KB for instance, a Query() or Scan() will read 4 entries for every RCU consumed.